# Images Wrapped With Links Don't Work

Tags: html

So I was trying to make an image be clickable. This is a SUPER easy thing to do, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't even acknowledge that there is a link.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="register"><img src="images/register.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="login"><img src="images/login.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks, guys. :)

The only css I think refers to it is:

```
A:link {text-decoration: none}
A:visited {text-decoration: none}
A:active {text-decoration: none}
A:hover {text-decoration: underline;color:#f60051}

#sidebar li {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Is the image appearing?  Does your mouse cursor change or recognize there is a link there? Also, make sure you close out your first image with a />

Comment: @PeeHaa It doesn't act like a link. The mouse doesn't change to pointer when hovered over. :/

Comment: @burmat The image appears, but it doesn't respond like a link.

Comment: Do you have any CSS or JavaScript that might be interfering?

Comment: Check to make sure your a:link in your css is not interfering with the fact you have links in an unordered list

Comment: Also, you can validate your html here http://validator.w3.org/, it might help. After that, you should disable Javascript and try again.

Comment: Heads up though, I can't select any text as well.

Comment: Can you drag and drop a page from the explorer pane onto the page in your ide?  What does the link look like that it creates?  Is it different from the one you've written?  Also, what happens if you take the link out of the list?  Will it work then?

Comment: Ah, a div was in front of everything, I believe that was the problem. Lemme check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a div in front of everything, so it was blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `<a href="register">` or `<a href="login">` is exactly what you have written?

They dont seem to be valid URLs. That might be the issue.

Try `<a href="register.php">` or `<a href="login.php">` or whatever the correct URL is.

Also you can override the default CSS Cursor for the image to make it a [pointer](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=pointer). Since cursor style can be inherited maybe it is taking value of a previous style declaration and such a declaration might solve the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't matter until it is actually clicked.

Comment: Yeah, @burmat is right. I'm using htaccess to cancel out the extension. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#register"><img src="images/register.png"></a></li>
<li><a href="#login"><img src="images/login.png"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, 'register' and 'login' are pages. But I'm using htaccess to cancel out the '.php' extension. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you may want to be more specific for "Doesn't work" as previously mentioned. I assume you mean the links don't work? You may want to specify the browser you are using and other details.

I however have come across similar problems before and this may help you out as well. I would sometimes get random links not working using your method, I eventually started changing the link wrapping an image to an image with an onclick event. This almost always helped.

```
<ul>
<li><img src="images/register.png" onclick="location.href='register'" style="cursor:pointer;"/></li>
<li><img src="images/login.png" onclick="location.href='login'" style="cursor:pointer;"/></li>
```

The onclick is simply a link and the cursor:pointer is just to make it look like a link when you hover over it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Like everyone has said before, make sure the url that goes in the location.href='' works and is correct.